# pre 2000 space mecha anime/cartoon very similar to gundam shows

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

Need help finding a title of an anime I watched many years ago. It must have been pre 2000. I remember parts of the story.

Started with a few pilots (maybe 4-5), cockpit looked very similar to *Star Trek* style control room; everyone sat inside, no fighter plane style cockpits. Robot did not split.

Initially it was on something like a large station on a planet surface, Then was launched into space. During the show it constantly fought enemy smaller spaceships by keeping fists out and they crashed into it (fists forward like Superman form)

At some point it fought with another robot in space, pulled out something like an axe and killed the other one.

Gets captured at some point, pilots locked in prison, somehow they escape, find the robot and fly out.

The look of the mecha was very very similar to old and even original *Gundam* shows when I searched online but none matched this.

More info:

- It was definitly japanese style of anime
- Watched it on VHS tapes in Russia
- Unsure of the language (I only remember that I did not
  understand the language)
- Set mostly in outer space
- Target Audience; I would estimate young children, I must have been 4-6 years old at the time

Comment: Shin Getter Robo?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Good question, but you might be able to improve it if you check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407).  What's a "railtrack?"

Comment: @DavidW - I assume he means a rocket sled track.

Comment: Thanks, added more info, something like a sled track in a big station and it was launched forward and eventually into space. It wasn't Shin Getter Robo, the look of the robot was almost identical to original gundam without a big gun or a shield

Comment: The fact that it had a cockpit similar to a control room makes me think about [Bryger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Cyclone_Braiger), but I don't think it matches the other criteria...

Comment: Unfortunately it is not Bryger

Answer (score 1):

It can possibly be Macross/ do you remember love,  the movie or unless you watched Robotech the series.  Basically everything you said happens in the series; Macross is the original serie version, but the USA made some changes and made Robotech. Japan later made a movie called Macross/ Do you remember love?, and is basically the same story but modified with some events different, yet same story.
Some years ago a spaceship lands on Earth and humans some what restore it and also make special mechas from the spaceship, later Earth is attacked because of this spaceship by other aliens. Some how this Spaceship ends up in space with a whole city on it. Now a war happenes everyother day between the humans and aliens. In one mission the humans get trapped and taken to a jail,  but they are able to escape on a spaceship.
Movie is from 1984, and the series late 70s or early 80s
Movie on YouTube

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I checked the names you mentioned, unfortunately they are not the show, although many parts of the story aligns. The major difference however is the shape of the "spaceship", it was almost identical to a gundam, with a big control room similar to a star trek style. Majority of the fighting also took place in space, I can't recall any combat on Earth